# Consumir WSDL SAP estructura compleja con VS2019 C#

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl, sap

no se como consumir este WSDL  VB 2019 C#

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando dices "No puedo", qué significa? Hay un error? Cuál?

Comment: no hay error no se consumirlo , no se como declarar y pasar las variables al ws

Comment: ZtdRfcPropuestasPropuestas(string,prueba2.wsdata2.zealvgenpro[] TBanco,prueba2.wsdata2.zealvgenpro[] Tdetalle,prueba2.wsdata2.zealvgenpro[] Tproveedor, String)

Comment: no se declarar los zealvgenpro[] y pasar al ws.

Comment: ya que son un arreglo

Answer (score 0):

finalmente pude consumir el WS
declarar los array(list) y las variables que lo contenian
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]